# Any way to specify module properties from an orchestrator (non-parent) pom?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a multi-module maven 3 project, in which I have an orchestrator/build pom whose sole job is to run the maven build.  Each module already has its parent pom, none of which are this orchestrator pom.

Is there any way from within the orchestrator pom to set/specify property values that would be used by the modules?  Since the modules do not inherit the orchestrator pom, they know nothing of any property values set/specified within it (ex: ${buildEngine} or ${cluster}).

For ex:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sbic</groupId>
    <artifactId>builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Orchestrator Pom</name>

    <properties>
        <buildEngine>Geronimo</buildEngine>
        <cluster>peanuts</cluster>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <!-- Supert POM Component Versionning -->
        <module>SbiComMavenCommon</module>

        <!-- Projects -->

        <module>../AlertServices</module>
        <module>../Configuration</module>
        <module>../Core</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

In order to build my project, I simply call `mvn package` on this builder pom.

What I am looking for is an ability to specify properties in this builder pom that would then be used by the modules, *WITHOUT* requiring the modules to have this pom in its parent tree.

For example, something that would accomplish the following (obviously not valid pom syntax):

```xml
<module>
   ../Core
   <properties>
     <name>SomeValue</name>
     <server>192.168.1.2</server>
   </properties>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it with Maven which I'm aware of. But, there is a workaround - use [properties:set-system-properties](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) from Properties Maven plugin

Of course, caveats apply, as for any **global shared mutable** state. For example, the module parent/child relationships are not respected. Though it looks like you **want it** anyway.